# How do we get Canonical to fix their certificates? I can't access Ubuntu Wiki

Tags: canonical, usability

I'm getting certificate errors when accessing Ubuntu Wiki. This is forcing me and I assume others who have rigorous security with their web browsing to create exceptions for these sites.

They have inappropriate certificates from GoDaddy that doesn't match their URLs. This is preventing me access (without intervention at the firewall).

Can this be fixed with a new certificate or must I (and everyone else that is security conscious) make an exception at the firewall?

Here's the error:

```
Untrusted Website
While trying to retrieve the URL:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Raid (Add exception for this URL)
Status
Hostname doesn't match
Subject
/O=*.canonical.com/OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=*.canonical.com
Issuer
/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./OU=http://certificates.godaddy.com/repository/CN=Go Daddy Secure Certification Authority/serialNumber=07969287
SHA1 Fingerprint
FB:99:C5:CA:22:9F:FD:A9:5D:AF:C1:EB:64:BA:AE:CC:97:DA:7F:02
MD5 Fingerprint
89:95:3B:97:07:FC:0D:3E:41:D4:92:34:42:18:61:71
Valid from
Jun 12 05:00:31 2012 GMT
Valid until
Jun 17 21:08:04 2013 GMT
```

Comment: Certificate looks fine from hear, maybe your root certificate on your computer is out of date? Expires 6/18/13

Comment: Really?  It is my understanding that if the URL matches the certificate Subject, which is one of the purposes of a Certificate Subject, these errors won't pop up.
Note:  True this is not a date issue, but there are other aspects of certs that may suggest inappropriate sources like the error here.

Comment: It appears that the hostname and the subject don't match.  This is a source of suspicion of invalid certs.  In essence I'd hope that Canonical would produce certificates with a subject specifying Ubuntu not Canonical.  That would clear up these errors.

Comment: URL: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/...
Cert Sbj: *.canonical.com

Comment: I think this is the RFC that describes why this is a problem and a security error. 

RFC Doc: https://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4945.txt

Comment: Key quotation: "Implementations MUST be capable of verifying that the IP address
   presented in ID matches via bitwise comparison the IP address present
   in the certificate's iPAddress field of the SubjectAltName extension.
   Implementations MUST perform this verification by default.  When
   comparing the contents of ID with the iPAddress field in the
   SubjectAltName extension for equality, binary comparison MUST be
   performed.  Note that certificates may contain multiple address
   identity types -- in which case, at least one must match the source
   IP.  "

Comment: I get a cert with CN `*.ubuntu.com` when visiting https://wiki.ubuntu.com/